# Determining a specific application's network transfer speed via command prompt?

Tags: command-line, command-prompt, bandwidth, query-performance, netstat

My goal is to create a network activity light for a specific program. I'm a mechanical guy, so I can figure out the hardware and the logic, but I have no clue where to start with the coding. Ultimately this needs to run without user interaction, so I figured some sort of script would be a good place to start. I tried looking at netstat -e, but I didn't see any obvious way to determine the bandwidth a specific application was using. Thoughts? I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished my goal using the "typeperf" command:

typeperf "\Process(FlashMediaLiveEncoder)\IO Data Bytes/sec"